# Regex to get n number of lines after a match

Tags: java, regex

I have some text an example of which is as follows:

```
Lactose Hydrogen Breath Test
  Time
        Time Point (min)
        H2  (ppm)
        H2 Change

    (ppm)
        Hydrogen (ppm)

        0937
        0
        0/0

        Time point (min)

        0
        10
        20
        30
        40
        50
        60
        70
        80
        90
        100


        Notes: Measurements at 120 and 150 mins are insignificant changes and are most probably due to sporadic error.

        Results are not consistent with Lactose malabsorption.

        Lactose intolerance is not suggested.

This is now some other text that can be anything
```

I just want to extract the first five lines after 'Notes' and leave behind all the other stuff (in this case up to Lactose intolerance is not suggested but there can be any kind of text after it.

I am using the current java to extract this:

```
public Map<String,String> LactoseTestExtractor(String str){

        Pattern match_pattern = Pattern.compile("Lactose Hydrogen Breath Test(.*?Interpretation[^\\r|^\\n]*)",Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher matchermatch_pattern = match_pattern.matcher(str);

        Pattern match_pattern2 = Pattern.compile("Lactose Hydrogen Breath Test.*?(Notes:.*?\\r|\\n[\\r|\\n]?.*?\\r|\\n[\\r|\\n]?)",Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher matchermatch_pattern2 = match_pattern2.matcher(str);

        if (matchermatch_pattern.find()) {
            lact=matchermatch_pattern.group(1).toString().trim();
            System.out.println("lact1"+lact);

        }

        else if (matchermatch_pattern2.find()){
            lact=matchermatch_pattern2.group(1).toString().trim();
            System.out.println("lact2"+lact);

        }
```

However I am getting the entire match back instead of just what I want which is:

```
Measurements at 120 and 150 mins are insignificant changes and are most probably due to sporadic error.

        Results are not consistent with Lactose malabsorption.

        Lactose intolerance is not suggested.
```

How can I correct? Not sure if its a java or a regex issue

Comment: Your input doesn't contain `Lactose Hydrogen Breath Test`, so why do either of those patterns match?

Comment: Why do you want to use regexp for this? Just search forn `Note`, substring from its location then split by `[\r\n]+` finally take the five first elements as available from the resulting array.

Comment: @Andy Turner- apologies I have changed the example

Comment: @A4L I think the regex is the simpler solution

Answer (score 1):

First of all, [Java 8 supports `\R`to match a linebreak](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lineending).

For the regex, you can use a lookbehind to match `Note:` and then the next 5 lines as follows:

```
(?<=Notes:)(.*\\R){5}
```

The result is in `group(0)`.